# Uncatchable exception when trying to open absent file from zip with wxWidgets

Tags: c++, exception, zip, wxwidgets, archive

I'm opening files directly from zip archives using the following code (simplified):

```
// prepare, used once:
wxFileSystem FileSystem;
wxFileSystem::AddHandler(new wxArchiveFSHandler);

// access a file, used many times:
wxFSFile *fs = NULL;
nStream buf;// nStream class is public wxInputStream, public wxOutputStream
try{
    fs = FileSystem.OpenFile("archive.zip#zip:somefile.txt);
    if(!fs) return false;
    // loaded:
    wxInputStream *inS = fs->GetStream();
    if(!inS)
    {    delete fs;
        return false;  }
    inS->Read(buf);
    delete inS;
}   catch(...)
{   return false;   }
// read file from buf here (using own stream class for convenience):
...
// done:
delete fs;
```

This code works Ok while files I'm trying to access exists in archive.

If `somefile.txt` is not in archive, program crashes at `FileSystem.OpenFile()` and `catch(...)` does **not** works. I never knew there are exceptions that can't be catched (that's the idea? Exceptions are to catch them!).

**The questions are:**

1. How to avoid this? I need my app not to crash while trying to access absent files.

I guess I can first open this zip with some wxWidgets class object, try to check if file I need to access exists and then unpack it. But I'm trying to avoid unnecessary coding around this and keep program code simple.

**More general questions:**

2. What's so special with exception in `wxFileSystem::OpenFile()`?
3. Is there a way to capture "uncatchable" exceptions?  And what's the idea behind them?

Comment: Segfaults, div by zero, and a whole family of other errors do not raise C++ style exceptions, and under normal circumstances you do not want to catch them. They mean your program state is probably utterly fubar, so trying to continue running is not a good idea. Let us in on the exception thrown and maybe someone can assist you.

Comment: IDE (Code::Blocks) shows no exception, just halts the execution. Running from command-line gives Segmentation error on halting.  Seems like manually opening zip archives is the only option left.

Comment: You are solving the problem the wrong way. There is a bug in your program because it segfaults and crashes, so you should attempt to locate that bug and fix it, instead of trying to continue execution regardless of the crash. Use a debugger to see where exactly it crashes, and what are the values of relevant variables.

Comment: Lauri Nurmi, as I have mentioned, `program crashes at FileSystem.OpenFile()`, so it seems like a wxWidgets bug. I'm not ready to dive into wx source code, so I'm just trying to get around of this.

Comment: @user3558897, that craqsh indicates that it is possible thwre is a bug in wxWidgets {archive} file system implementation. It is also possible that it is something simple. Why not try to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following:

1. Code works Ok when there is no multithreading (I have a lots of threads in real app where it falls),
2. `wxFileSystem` is **not** thread-safe in any way, at least with ZipHandler added (even when I create own wxFileSystem instance in each thread, it still fails to open non-existing file in archive),
3. The simplest working solution was to open an archive and check all entries for filename I need (before accessing zipped file directly) with the code like this:

   bool FileExistInZip(wxString zipfname, wxString fname)
   {   // check if file exists inside zip:
       wxFFileInputStream in(zipfname);
       wxZipInputStream zip(in);
       wxZipEntry* entry=NULL;
       while (entry=zip.GetNextEntry(), entry!=NULL)
       {   // access meta-data:
           bool found = entry->GetName()==inzipf;
           delete entry;
           if(found)   return true;
       }
   }